# Comparing dates in sql Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i am trying to run a query in mysql to select all records from a table where the "end_date" of that record is greater than or equal to the current date, but it keeps coming up with "MySQL returned an empty result set".  But such a record definitely exists n my table, is there a problem with my query?

this is the value in the end_date column for the one record "03/24/2014".

and this is my query

```
SELECT * FROM ******** WHERE DATE(end_date) > DATE(CURDATE())
```

I have my suspicions however that it may be the date format meaning the date format on my computer might be like this: dd/MM/yyyy
Whereas the date format on the server might be like this : MM/dd/yyyy

Unfortunately if that is the case i dunno what to do about that yet.

Comment: Why are you **not** storing dates in the `date` type?

Comment: Uhmm...i dunno i thought it would be easier saving and retrieving the dates from php to the database that way Was i wrong?

Comment: Oho!! Thank you, i changed that and it worked, i feel really silly though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comment by @FreshPrinceOfSO, better to store date as real DATE, TIMESTAMP, or DATETIME.

If that's not an option--it's not your db to alter for example--then Mysql has a `STR_TO_DATE()` function you can use:

```
      SELECT * FROM ******** 
          WHERE STR_TO_DATE(end_date,'%m/%d/%Y')  > CURDATE();
```

HOWEVER...
If end_date column has an index, the function applied to it will nullify the index benefit.